# How to validate html file without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

If the browser disabled the javascript , then how to validate the html file ? I am not talking about 'how to enable javascript, but how to validate the html form without using javascript ? This question is asked by an interviewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form validation must **always** be performed server-side.  Client side validation is great, but optional.  Surely this is what the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: He writes "validate the html file" which does not make any sense. I think he means form validation like you said. Great answer.

Comment: Thank you!
Yea that is html form.
Client side validation is possible in html5 right ?

Comment: @ran - yes HTML5 provides means of restricting user input, but that is not something that could be relied on if JavaScript is disabled. The user may be using a browser like IE that does not support these html5 features.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer one of the example from [How to validate html for input without using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798046/how-to-validate-html-form-input-without-using-javascript).

> Javascript is the only way to validate the data on the client side
>   before it is submitted. Since Javascript can be disabled, your
>   server-side code should always validate any submitted data before
>   using it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what 'validate' means in that context (might be a good chance for you to ask a follow up question on what he/she means on html validation?)

Anyway, I am assuming that they are talking about HTML markup validation then there are online services like:

- http://validator.w3.org/

If the interviewer is talking about validation in terms of client-side validation (eg user age must contain range between X to Yetc), then you might need to validate the input on the server (eg with server side code).